# Global IP on DomU in XEN, using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xen

Can a DomU have a global IP in Xen? I see that DomU's are connected to Dom0 and then physical ethernet using xenbridges, so is it technically possible in Xen to assign global IPs to DomU so it can be pinged/accessed by the outside world?

Is there any config changes in Xen that I need to do? Can `network-route` be of some help if used in place of `network-bridge`?

Comment: Yes, you can.  As long as you're routing isn't in some way special (RFC1918 network for Dom0, for example), you'll don't even have to do anything special  (just treat it like any physical machine in the network).  If your Dom0 is in the same network as DomU, you're absolutely fine (anything else would need special care, but should be generally possible).

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on how your ISP gives your additional public IPs and how it wants them to be used inside on your network.

There are at least two possibilities:

1) Your ISP wants your primary public IP to act as a router, that routes packets to the final destination. That is, in the network layer 2, Ethernet frames containing IP packets for either of your public IPs are both delivered to the MAC address of your physical Ethernet interface.

Then it is the task of the dom0 to route the IP packets to your VM.

2) Your ISP offers you a normal Ethernet network (ISP router uses ARP to find out the MAC address of the IP address used by the VM). In this case you can just create a bridge that has your existing outside world interface as one member, and then the VMs use that bridge for their networking.

Then you need just to assign public IPs to the VMs and their ethernet devices that are connected to this bridge.